# How to create Java VM using C++ Android Native code on Windows Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, visual-studio-2019, clang++

My main question is how can I create a Java VM using C++ Android Native Code using Windows Visual Studio 2019?
I will write down some workaround I tried to find a solution to that problem:

I tried to follow this tutorial: https://calebfenton.github.io/2017/04/05/creating_java_vm_from_android_native_code/ . To create the Java VM so I could call functions from an .jar (Java library) I have, but It doesn't work as I need to use the **dlfcn.h** library that couldn't be found in my Visual Studio installation.

So I tried to use this: https://github.com/dlfcn-win32/dlfcn-win32 as it is needed to create the Java VM on Android using C++ Native code, here is the example code on the tutorial:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <jni.h>
typedef int (*JNI_CreateJavaVM_t)(void *, void *, void *);
typedef jint (*registerNatives_t)(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz);
static int init_jvm(JavaVM **p_vm, JNIEnv **p_env) {
  // https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/ce3a0a5/services/surfaceflinger/DdmConnection.cpp
  JavaVMOption opt[4];
  opt[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/data/local/tmp/shim_app.apk";
  opt[1].optionString = "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_android_adb,suspend=n,server=y";
  opt[2].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=/data/local/tmp";
  opt[3].optionString = "-verbose:jni"; // may want to remove this, it's noisy
  JavaVMInitArgs args;
  args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
  args.options = opt;
  args.nOptions = 4;
  args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;
  void *libdvm_dso = dlopen("libdvm.so", RTLD_NOW);
  void *libandroid_runtime_dso = dlopen("libandroid_runtime.so", RTLD_NOW);
  if (!libdvm_dso || !libandroid_runtime_dso) {
    return -1;
  }
  JNI_CreateJavaVM_t JNI_CreateJavaVM;
  JNI_CreateJavaVM = (JNI_CreateJavaVM_t) dlsym(libdvm_dso, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
  if (!JNI_CreateJavaVM) {
    return -2;
  }
  registerNatives_t registerNatives;
  registerNatives = (registerNatives_t) dlsym(libandroid_runtime_dso, "Java_com_android_internal_util_WithFramework_registerNatives");
  if (!registerNatives) {
    return -3;
  }
  if (JNI_CreateJavaVM(&(*p_vm), &(*p_env), &args)) {
    return -4;
  }
  if (registerNatives(*p_env, 0)) {
    return -5;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But the dlfcn.c internally uses **<Windows.h>** library, so when I am trying to build my C++ project using **Clang 5.0** to generate the "Android .so", it didn't work as "Windows.h" library was not recognized, I also tried to put only the header and the dlfcn.dll generated from that github project using CMake but I cannot use **__declspec(dllimport)** as it is not recognized when it is building the library for Android (using Clang), so I cannot bind correctly the functions to call to open the **libdvm.so** necessary to start the JVM to call Java functions (in .jar file) on C++.

Comment: *it gives me an error,* isnt a working problem description. You are like asking 3 questions in one. And to be precise: by calling .jar functions, what you want to do is to run some java code that sits in that jar?

Comment: @GhostCat I improved my post as you said and I only have just one question about how to create the Java VM using C++ on Windows

Comment: Why would you use a Windows-specific component (dlfcn-win32) when developping for Android? Unix-like systems have native support for `dlfcn` in `libdl.so`

Comment: _"I need to use the dlfcn.h library that couldn't be found in my Visual Studio installation"_. Shouldn't you be building your native code with the Android NDK though? Maybe Visual Studio can be configured to use the toolchains provided in the NDK, but that's not something I'm familiar with. The header `dlfcn.h` is available in the NDK in any case.

Comment: @Michael Currently I have managed to solve this problem temporarily by obtaining the pointer to the java environment from the activity in the "android_main" function doing: "state->activity->env" but that is temporal because I cannot define some parameters like java class path on the optionString.